# Learning to read official documents and tables in Danish

Tags: reading, danish, specialist-vocabulary

In Denmark most of the online tax filing system is only in Danish. The vocabulary is highly specialized and, even if one understands it, the concepts are challenging. A foreigner has to engage with the system more deeply than a native, as they often have foreign possessions and income. Furthermore, the content needs to be understood exactly; getting a good general impression of what is probably meant is not enough.

What are good techniques for learning to read official government documents and forms, and instructions for their use?

Comment: For starters, here are many tax-related documents in English: https://www.skat.dk/skat.aspx?oId=5378&filter=US&lang=US. Some important Danish words are included in them.

Answer (score 1):

Often it isn't the case. Surely our government choose more officiel words, and fill out all sentences after the book, which we Danes attend not to do, so it seems more overwhelming. The solution would be to learn some more officiel synonyms.

Our government writes, so the bottom of our society can understand it too, they just choose more officiel words, that can be harder to read fast, but clearly just are more officiel synonyms to the everyday language.

Keep in mind, that our system includes a tsunami of twisted, old and complex rules and laws, that surely forced our government to be clear in their messages, so no confuseness can take place.

As an example of how Danish government and an everyday Dane would say the same thing differently:

**The Danish Government (Taken from www.borger.dk)**

*Enhver person, der har bopæl i Danmark (dvs. er tilmeldt folkeregistret), har ret til alle offentlige sundhedsydelser. Dine rettigheder dokumenteres ved sundhedskortet, som du får fra din bopælskommune.*

**Now here is how I'd quote the same explanation to my friend**

*Alle i Danmark har ret til velfærdsydelser. Du får dine rettigheder med dit sygesikring.*

I see that this is "super random" as an example, the bottom of the line is, that this is how two Danes would say it to each other, or similar. Not half as explaining in the tone, less official, and even removing parts of words, as we have official and unofficial slang every Dane use, but the government doesn't.

Let me know if you have examples, so I can try to break that down instead of something that might me irrelevant as my example.